# How to use string value from SQL database to change the color of buttons?

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to make a parking lot management system. I want to get the occupied spots from SQL database and change the button of colors related to the occupied spots (spots are saved as same names with buttons in the sql db). My buttons located in a tabcontrol and separated between 3 pages as "blue", "yellow", "purple". Blue buttons starts with "b", yellow buttons starts with "y", purple buttons starts with "p" and they all go like: b1,b2,b3,y1,y2,y3,p1,p2,p3...
For example: b1 (blue page button 1) is occupied and the program will turn its color to red.

Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```cs
public static string databasePath = "parklotdata.db";
public static string connectionString = $"Data Source={databasePath};Version=3;";

public static List<string> spots_occupied = new List<string>();

static void color_occupied()
{
    admin_panel ap = new admin_panel();
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = @"SELECT spot FROM parkinglot WHERE occupied=1";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
        SQLiteDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            string spot = rd[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Spot: {spot}");
            Control[] targetcontrol = ap.tabControl1.Controls.Find(spot, true);
            if (targetcontrol != null)
            {
                targetcontrol[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"Color changed for {spot}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to save a Boolean value to the database to represent the occupied state - `true` for occupied and `false` for vacant. You can then create a custom control that inherits `Button` and adds an `IsOccupied` property of type `bool`. In the setter of that property, you would set the `BackColor` to the corresponding `Color` value.

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Don't try to overcome everything in a single method. Use separate methods. For example first get the SQL query results in a method and then use these results to update your buttons.

Comment: The code as presented never calls your (poorly named IMHO} method `color_occupied()` here.  Perhaps create a class Perhaps called "ParkingSpots" and then a  `public List<ParkingSpots> GetOccupiedParkingSpots()` method that JUST returns a list of those, THEN use that list in another method.